# Way to force merge/rebase conflict on a specific file

Tags: git

I have a text file in my repo that, by nature of its content, I want to never be automatically merged. I want it to always (assuming there are changes in both branches) generate <<<<<======>>>>> conflict blocks.
I figured there should be way to do this using .gitattributes, got to merge drivers and now a little lost in syntax.

Comment: have you looked into the `.gitattributes` file at all? https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html